# laravel file is not updating

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i have been working on my project for several week. everything was fine. but today all of a sudden i can not load some of my changed views (some i can change and get result). even if i change the controller, its still now working. according to SO and some other site i have tried followings

- restart browser
- clear browser cache, history(even tried new browser)
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan view:clear
- composer dumpautoload
- delete all files from storage/framework/views folder
- delete all files from storage/framework/sessions folder
- restart nginx server

what did i miss. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Run `php artisan view:clear` command to clear views cache. If this won't help, delete all `php` files in `storage/framework/views` directory.

Another thing you should do is to check if you're calling the view you want. It happens in big projects with a similar views. Use Laravel Debugbar to display actually loaded views.